HTML linting error (',' expected javascript), but following the suggestion breaks the code
I'm making a small flask app (and am VERY new to html) and have a linting error that's confusing me.  In my html file I have this:
<button onclick="copyText('{{ results['s'] }}')">Copy to clipboard</button> 

<script>
    function copyText(txt) {
        // copy txt into clipboard 
        // put txt in format '{{ TXT }}' if you want the value of the variable not a string literal
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(txt);
    }
</script>

The line '{{ results['s'] }}' is underlined with red and vscode says "',' expected javascript" twice, right before s and right after s. (Meaning to get rid of the error I have to write '{{ results[',s,'] }}').
I tried adding in the commas which fixed the linting error but that broke my code and the button didn't work when I ran the flask app. I also tried adding <!-- vscode-disable-next-line --> right before the button line (as suggested by chatGPT) but that didn't make a difference for the linting error.
Really I'd just like to know why the error is there and how to get rid of it.

Are you using eslint?  I've never heard of a vscode disable, but that's just me. Also, gpt isn't bullet proof and wouldn't recommend it.

Not to mention the suggestion of it using html comments where you'd need a JavaScript comment, unless I just don't get what it's suggesting.

That's not really HTML. It's a Jinja template that gets then rendered into HTML. And unescaped single quotes inside single quotes is not valid JavaScript syntax.

I think you should use `` instead of ''. Try this:
<button onclick="copyText(`{{ results['s'] }}`)">Copy to clipboard</button>

<script>
  function copyText(txt) {
    // copy txt into clipboard
    // put txt in format '{{ TXT }}' if you want the value of the variable not a string literal
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(txt);
  }
</script>


thank you so much!!!! it worked and the error went away
